# Timing Kernel launches in CUDA while using Thrust

Tags: c, time, cuda, thrust

Kernel launches in CUDA are generally asynchronous, which (as I understand) means that once the CUDA kernel is launched control returns immediately to the CPU. The CPU continues doing some useful work while the GPU is busy number crunching 
unless the CPU is forcefully stalled using `cudaThreadsynchronize()` or `cudaMemcpy()` .

Now I have just started using the [Thrust](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/) library for CUDA. Are the function calls in Thrust 
synchronous or asynchronous?

In other words, if I invoke `thrust::sort(D.begin(),D.end());` where D is a device vector, does it make sense to measure the sorting time using

```
        start = clock();//Start

             thrust::sort(D.begin(),D.end());

        diff = ( clock() - start ) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        std::cout << "\nDevice Time taken is: " <<diff<<std::endl;
```

If the function call is asynchronous then diff will be  0 seconds  for any vector (which is junk for timings), but if it is synchronous I will indeed get the real time performance.

Comment: I'm skeptical of using ```clock``` for timing thrust, due to its lousy resolution. It hasn't worked well for me in the past. You should use the CUDA event API instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thrust calls which invoke kernels are asynchronous, just like the underlying CUDA APIs thrust uses. Thrust calls which copy data are synchronous, just like the underlying CUDA APIs thrust uses.

So your example would only be measuring the kernel launch and thrust host side setup overheads, not the operation itself. For timing, you can get around this by calling either `cudaThreadSynchronize` or  `cudaDeviceSynchronize` (the later in CUDA 4.0 or later) after the thrust kernel launch. Alternatively, if you include a post kernel launch copy operation and record the stop time after that, your timing will include setup, execution, and copying time.

In your example this would look something like

```
   start = clock();//Start 

   thrust::sort(D.begin(),D.end()); 
   cudaThreadSynchronize(); // block until kernel is finished

   diff = ( clock() - start ) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC; 
   std::cout << "\nDevice Time taken is: " <<diff<<std::endl;
```

Comment: That's not exactly right, most are asynchronous but some are not. http://groups.google.com/group/thrust-users/browse_thread/thread/8fd88a9987cad036 Also, thrust calls that return a value, like reduction, are blocking http://groups.google.com/group/thrust-users/msg/cd7542285070f893 And cudaHostSynchronize should be cudaDeviceSynchronize.

Comment: dont you need to use events for calcualting the device execution time ?