# Should we use cuda Event to time thrust function (such as sort) or should we use cpu timers

Tags: timer, cuda, gpu

I am trying to time the thrust sort function . Present, i am using cuda events. but i was curious if cuda events will give me the wrong value.  This is because, on my computer, thrust is sorting 2 million floats in GPU in 34 ms. But this seems too fast

I tried both CPU and GPU times and got following:

CPU ( takes around 36 ms)

```
__int64 ctr1 = 0 , ctr2 = 0 , freq = 0 ;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency((LARGE_INTEGER *) &freq);
    QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER *) &ctr1);
    thrust::sort(D.begin(),D.end());
    // transfer data back to host   
    thrust::copy(D.begin(), D.end(), H.begin());
    cudaThreadSynchronize(); // block until kernel is finished

   QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER *)&ctr2);
    double ans = ((ctr2 - ctr1) * 1.0 / freq);
    printf("The time elapsed in milliseconds is %f\n",(ans*1000));
```

GPU

```
cudaEvent_t start, stop;
cudaEventCreate(&start);
cudaEventCreate(&stop);
cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
thrust::sort(D.begin(),D.end());

thrust::copy(D.begin(), D.end(), H.begin());
cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
float elapsedTime; 
cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsedTime , start, stop);
printf("time is %f ms", elapsedTime);
```

Please let me know which timing is correct

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091219/timing-kernel-launches-in-cuda-while-using-thrust

Comment: Perhaps you could try both approaches to timing and compare them? The host code to use a high resolution timer around a code section is pretty trivial to write and run.

Comment: @talonmies: done. Please suggest which reading is more accurate

Comment: @Programmer: surely those timings remove any doubts about the sort speed? If the GPU events were showing much, much less time, then you could assume they were wrong. But the 2ms difference (if statistically significant) is easily explained by Brano's answer.

Comment: @Programmer: Why does it seem too fast to you? ```thrust::sort``` should achieve ~1B keys/sec on a GTX 480. That suggests it should take ~2ms to sort 2M 32b keys on that GPU. Your post doesn't indicate what hardware you're profiling, so it's impossible to say if your timings are reasonable or not.

Comment: @JaredHoberock:we are talking about a GE force GT 540 M with 2 multiprocessors. The global memory size if ard 1.9gb. DOes the time look reasonable

Comment: @Programmer: Yes, it looks reasonable for 2 SMs. You should accept brano's answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both timings are correct from different aspects. The CPU timing will include the overhead caused by the API calls and the synchronization. If you are interested in this overhead you should use the CPU timer.

The event based timing is isolating the timing on the GPU and gives you the time of the GPU execution.

Other differences between CPU and Event Timing is that if the thrust::sort() is the first call to the GPU from the current thread the call to will need to setup the CUDA context and give you a timing which includes the context setup. You will not get this problem if you use the event based timing because the context will be setup when calling cudaEventCreate().

If you want to time GPU algorithms to in order to get a performance figure, the best way to do this is to use event based timing but also run the algorithms in a loop a number of times.

```
cudaEvent_t start, stop;
cudaEventCreate(&start);
cudaEventCreate(&stop);
cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
for(int i=0; i < 100; i++){
thrust::sort(D.begin(),D.end());

thrust::copy(D.begin(), D.end(), H.begin());
}
cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
float elapsedTime; 
cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsedTime , start, stop);
printf("Avg. time is %f ms", elapsedTime/100);
```

Comment: what if I do some work on the CPU and then do some work on the GPU. How do i calculate the total time then?

Comment: @Programmer for all practical purposes CPU timers should be OK as long as you synchronize properly. They may be more valuable to you because they include the overheads required to launch a kernel, synchronize it and so on. The CUDA event timer may be of academic value when you are trying to see how much time your algirithm takes to run on the GPU.

Answer (score 0):

Neither. I would recommend you to use **NVIDIA Visual Profiler**  that is shipped with CUDA SDK. It will tell you the accurate timing against each process on GPU. For more information on the tool visit its [Page](http://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-visual-profiler).

Comment: Never use nvidia visual profiler for timing purposes. It is not accurate at all because it inserts a lot of code in YOUR code to time your code

Comment: I've been into CUDA development for past 2 years. I'm also NVIDIA Certified CUDA Programmer. So I'm saying this with experience. The C timer never gives you the accurate timing because it time events on host. The cuda timer can give you good timing but not in as much detail as the Visual Profiler. Besides Visual Profiler is also recommeneded by NVIDIA.